# CakePHP: Prevent Auth component's "authError" message on homepage

Tags: cakephp

I have a CakePHP project where I modified "app/config/routes.php" so that the root points to the "Users" controller's "dashboard" action. In other words, these two URLs go to the same place:

http://example.com/

http://example.com/users/dashboard

I have the "Auth" component set up in my "App" controller like so:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    var $components = array('Auth', 'Session');

    function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->authorize = 'controller';
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard');

        if ($this->Auth->user()) {
            $this->set('logged_in', true);
        }
        else {
            $this->set('logged_in', false);
        }
    }
}
```

I want it so that if a non-authenticated user goes straight to http://example.com/users/dashboard , they are taken to the login page *with* the "Auth" component's "authError" message showing, but if they go to http://example.com/ , they are taken to the login page *without* the "Auth" component's "authError" message showing. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this by putting the following code in my "Users" controller's "login" action:

```
if ($this->Session->read('Auth.redirect') == $this->webroot && $this->Session->read('Message.auth.message') == $this->Auth->authError) {
    $this->Session->delete('Message.auth');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

been looking for somthing like that for a long time! Thank you.

I had to make a little change then `$this->webroot` is not "/":

```
if (str_replace("//","/",$this->webroot.$this->Session->read('Auth.redirect')) == $this->webroot && $this->Session->read('Message.auth.message') == $this->Auth->authError) {
    $this->Session->delete('Message.auth');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't understand why sometimes you show the error and why sometimes not.. but you can afford this creating an isAuthorized method and modifying all the logic of the default AuthComponent behavior.

Open your Auth component and check for method "startup()". There, at it's last line, you will se this:

```
$this->Session->setFlash($this->authError, $this->flashElement, array(), 'auth');
$controller->redirect($controller->referer(), null, true);
```

This is the part responsible for displaying the error.

Before it, you will se...

```
if ($this->isAuthorized($type)) {
    return true;
}
```

So you can change your isAuthorized method to change this message when you want.

Is a lot of work for (I think..) nothing.

PS. There may be a simpler way to be ignoring me

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Think about it. Somebody goes to your websites homepage and the very first thing they see is a message that says "Access denied". Not very friendly, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wants to prevent `authError` message on homepage and simple redirect to login page then you have to put `false` as parameter of `authError`

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public function initialize() {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authError' => false
        ]);
    }

}
```